# Are Transmission delay and queuing delay overlapping in nature. I am confused, the time transmission delays will take will also be added in queuing?

Tags: networking, delay

Queuing Delay  At the queue, the packet experiences a queuing delay as it waits to be transmitted  onto the link. The length of the queuing delay of a specific packet will depend on the  number of earlier-arriving packets that are queued and waiting for transmission onto  the link. If the queue is empty and no other packet is currently being transmitted, then  our packet’s queuing delay will be zero. On the other hand, if the traffic is heavy and  many other packets are also waiting to be transmitted, the queuing delay will be long.  We will see shortly that the number of packets that an arriving packet might expect  to find is a function of the intensity and nature of the traffic arriving at the queue.  Queuing delays can be on the order of microseconds to milliseconds in practice.

Transmission Delay  Assuming that packets are transmitted in a first-come-first-served manner, as is common in packet-switched networks, our packet can be transmitted only after all the  packets that have arrived before it have been transmitted. Denote the length of the
packet by L bits, and denote the transmission rate of the link from router A to router  B by R bits/sec. For example, for a 10 Mbps Ethernet link, the rate is R = 10 Mbps;  for a 100 Mbps Ethernet link, the rate is R = 100 Mbps. The transmission delay is  L/R. This is the amount of time required to push (that is, transmit) all of the packet’s  bits into the link. Transmission delays are typically on the order of microseconds to  milliseconds in practice.

Comment: If you’ve ever been to an amusement park, you’ve experienced what life is like for an outgoing packet:  first you have to wait in line to get on the roller coaster (“queueing delay”), and then once you’re on the roller coaster; more time passes before you get to the end of the ride (“transmission delay”).

Comment: Got it. I was thinking from a perspective of multiple packets. Delays are to thought only from a single packet journey. But to add a point , I guess Transmission delay is the time to   tie sit belt on the ride and be ready , while time to pass on ride till end is Propagation delay.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is it not a practical programming question